# How to decode a base64 file with command line tools

Tags: windows, base64, decode

I am trying to decode a base64 file using command line on my PC. The file contains a large block of encoded text.

Any solution?

Answer (score 7):

Windows has a utility named certutil which performs a variety of operations on certificates.  Because certificates are sometimes encoded in base64, certutil contains encode and decode operations that can be used on any file, not just certificates.

To decode, just:

certutil -decode *inputfile* *outputfile*

Details are at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil