# Decode base64 text in command line. Getting error

Tags: windows, command-line, base64

This might be a very simple question to ask:

How to decode base64 text/file in the command line?  Trying below statement to decode

```
echo QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ== | base64 --decode
```

I'm getting an error: 'base64' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.

The error is suggesting I do need to install package/library/utility. I tried a few from the internet but unfortunately none of working for me.

*I have already seen tons of questions on StackOverflow talking about the same thing, but none of them seem to solve my confusion.*

Few references I read:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/178521/how-can-i-decode-a-base64-string-from-the-command-line

https://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/base64/#Download

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/

**Can someone help me to set this up? Thanks!**

Comment: the error message sound like a windows message. Then try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454106/how-to-decode-a-base64-file-with-command-line-tools/64454476#64454476) or just use an online decoder like https://www.base64decode.org/  Please add an operating system tag to your question to avoid confusion

Comment: @jps thank you for the suggestion. I’ve added the windows tag.

Comment: Windows doesn't have a base64 program included.  In Unix and its derivatives, you can chain together many small programs to get things done.  Windows doesn't work like that, every program that works with base64 is expected to include its own code for dealing with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your Bash prompt, your command will work (the base64 tool is omnipresent in unix environments, you're very unlikely to need to install it as a package... as long as you are in the correct shell in the first place!)

Depending on your system, you might be able to access your linux environment just by typing 'bash' and pressing return at the command prompt. Though I'd also expect there to be a special entry in your Start Menu for it.

p.s. even just normal Git Bash will work if you have it